# read() stdin in c?

Tags: c, input, stdin

I have a quick little question involving the read() command.

I am really rusty in C, and unfortunately, my current assignment has me programming in C.
We need to read stdin using the read() and not fgets and the like.

So I have a simple while loop:

```
int n, i;
char buffer[257], *input;

while((n=read(fileno(stdin), buffer, 256)) > 0)
                {
                        buffer[n] ='\0';
                        if(buffer[n] = '\n') break;
                        write(input, buffer, strlen(buffer));
                }
```

So I am not sure how to make this loop stop at the press of enter (end of line) so that's why I have the break code, though I don't know if that's done correctly.

The whole objective I am trying to accomplish is to put the input from stdin into the pointer 'input'

(I am really bad at understanding pointers so bear with me :) )

My problem is that I am getting segmentation faults when I press enter.
I wish I could use fgets because then all this would be solved with a simple

```
input = fgets(buffer, 256, stdin);
```

Darn homework :(
Anyways, if any of you could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: `if(buffer[n] = '\n') break;` I think you intended `if(n && buffer[n-1] == '\n') break;` ( or maybe even `if(n==1 && buffer[n-1] == '\n') break;`. Also `write(input, buffer, strlen(buffer));` could be replaced by `write(input, buffer, n);`

Comment: Your code is like `x = 1; if (x == 0) { /*...*/ }`. Can you spot the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going about it all wrong. Firstly, `write` is a system call that's used to write to a **open file descriptor**. Your `input` is nothing like that - a file descriptor is gained by calling the `open` syscall first, or referring to one of the always-open files, e.g. `stdin`, `stdout` or `stderr`. Not to mention that a file descriptor is an `int` on Linux.

Also, you should remember that the assumption of your input on `stdin` ending with a newline doesn't have to be right all the time. Your program may receive some content on standard input that doesn't contain any newlines, for example contents of some file (redirected to `stdin`), or the input from keyboard may simply end with a `Ctrl-D` (EOF) instead of the "return" key.

On top of all that, **an uninitialized pointer doesn't refer to any valid memory**. The declaration of `char *input` doesn't give you any right to write/read the memory referred to by `input` unless you allocate some memory that this pointer will point to first.

Copying strings in C is achieved by using functions declared in `<string.h>`. They operate on C-strings, e.g. sequences of characters terminated by `\0`. In this case, `read()` doesn't terminate its output by a `\0`, in which case you'll want to use the `memcpy` function instead. Why don't you simply try reading directly into `input`, though? It doesn't make much sense to read to `buffer` first, simply to copy the data to another chunk of memory later on.

Also, the specification of `read` states that it reads **up to *count*** bytes from the file descriptor. Which means that if your `buffer` is declared as `char[257]`, then you should call `read(stdin,buffer,257)`, not 256. It would probably also be more suitable to simply declare the buffer as a 256-element array.

I hope that I've straightened out some stuff for you.

Comment: Ahh thanks, that makes a lot more sense! I changed the while loop to just simply read into input 'while((n=read(fileno(stdin), input, 256))>0) and I allocated memory to *input so now it seems like everything should be in working order now! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Your `input` dosn't point anywhere valid. You need to either allocate some memory (and free it when you're done) or make it point to valid storage.

Also `=` is assignment; `==` is comparison.

Comment: Adding to that, `if(buffer[n] == '\n') break;` could never be true, since the line just before it set that character to 0. Also, write() writes to a file descriptor, not a char pointer.

Comment: Ok, so what should I do to allocate some memory (sorry, bad with C). It all worked fine with fgets so I'm not sure what I should do about that. Also, since write is strictly for file descriptors, what should I use to assign what I read into *input? Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Be sure to read the documentation for the functions you use. When checking on the 'net I like to use [the POSIX.1-2008 site](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).